# How to diagnose lifetime errors

Tags: rust

How do you diagnose lifetime error messages? I am less interested in the answer to a particular problem and more how to find the solution.

Consider the following error:

```rust
mismatched types
expected struct `std::iter::Map<ndarray::iter::Iter<'b, _, _>, for<'b> fn(&'b _) -> &'b CellValue<'a>>`
   found struct `std::iter::Map<ndarray::iter::Iter<'_, _, _>, for<'a> fn(&'a _) -> &CellValue<'_> {what::<'_, '_>}>
```

At first glance, Rust has decided to claim that each of the `'b` lifetimes must be the same. However, as you can see in the code below, no such constraint was made explicitly. How do you get the compiler to tell you how it inferring this constraint?

```rust
fn what<'cellref, 'cell: 'cellref>(x: &f64) -> &'cellref CellValue<'cell> {
    &CellValue::Number(*x)
}

pub trait IterCellValue<'cellref, 'cell: 'cellref, I: Iterator<Item = &'cellref CellValue<'cell>>> {
    fn iter_cellvalue(&self) -> I;
}

impl<'a: 'b, 'b> IterCellValue<'b, 'a, std::iter::Map<ndarray::iter::Iter<'b, f64, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 2]>>, fn(&f64) -> &CellValue<'a>>> for ndarray::Array2<f64> {
    fn iter_cellvalue(&self) -> std::iter::Map<ndarray::iter::Iter<'b, f64, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 2]>>, fn(&f64) -> &CellValue<'a>> {
        let x = self.iter();
        // TODO
        x.map(what).into_iter()
    }
}

impl<'cellref, 'cell: 'cellref> IterCellValue<'cellref, 'cell, ndarray::iter::Iter<'cellref, CellValue<'cell>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 2]>>> for ndarray::Array2<CellValue<'cell>> {
    fn iter_cellvalue(&self) -> ndarray::iter::Iter<'cellref, CellValue<'cell>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 2]>> {
        self.iter()
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but `what` won't compile anyway: you're trying to return a reference to a temporary value: [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f1884a5ddfb347c0f901dce16db70e3f)

Comment: Ok, so if the trait expects an iterator of &T, how do you create a &T by mapping?

Comment: I don't think this have a single answer. With time, you gain experience and learn to know where to look and what to search.